# Redirect Passport Login Based on MongoDB Find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have the login route `router.post('/login', authController.login).` My controller uses passport and looks like:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login',
  successRedirect: '/',
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in'
});
```

This works fine but I want to redirect to `/store` if the user doesn't has a device and `/device` if they do, based on the query:

```
const devices = await Device.find({ owner: req.user._id });
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried:

```
router.post('/login', authController.login, deviceController.hasDevice);

exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Failed Login'
 });
 next();
};

exports.hasDevice = async (req, res) => {
  const devices = await Device.find({ owner: req.user._id });
  if (!devices.length) {
    res.render('store', { title: 'Store' });
  } else {
    res.render('devices', { title: 'My Devices', devices });
  }
};
```

but there is no user object on req when I get to hasDevice. I.e. I get "cannot find _id of undefined."

Comment: Aside from setup, there's a couple of flaws here. 1. You say you want to "redirect", but these are not redirects, and merely rendering different content on the same `/login` URL. 2. Typically you would not "pass data" on a redirect anyway, so it really should be up to the `/devices` route and controller to fetch that data. 3. The concept of `hasDevice` looking up a foreign model is "very relational" and causing an additional hit on the database per request. Better to add `deviceCount` to the `User` model if this is important to the application usage pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do was solved simply by using redirects like:

```
router.get('/', someController.findRoute));

exports.findRoute= async (req, res) => {
  const devices = await Device.find({ owner: req.user._id });
  if (!devices.length) {
    res.redirect('/store');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/devices');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using **Custom Callback** in `passport.authenticate()`.

```
router.post('/login', async function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }

        const devices = await Device.find({ owner: user._id });

        if (!devices.length) {
            res.render('store', { title: 'Store' });
        } else {
            res.render('devices', { title: 'My Devices', devices });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```